# Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class. Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.5:wsdl2java

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I'm getting error as Two declarations cause a collision in the Object Factory class.

This is when i tried to generate java classes from wsdl file.Please check and help me out if i need to remove any thing from SOAP WSDL.

Below is the error.Please give me solution to fix this.Below is the error from console when i do maven build.Provide me binding class for below issue if that is the only solution.Firstly i tried with JAXB framework,which was not created java files and no error also..Now i tried with CXF plugin and getting this error.

`````
[ERROR] http://g2vmcfgsvc04.olqa.preol.dell.com:8080/ConfigService/V3/ConfigDataService.svc? 
     xsd=xsd2 
     [0:0]: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
      com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: 
     http://g2vmcfgsvc04.olqa.preol.dell.com:8080/ConfigService/V3/ConfigDataService.svc?xsd=xsd2; 
     lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
     at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
     at  
    com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate
    (ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:191)
    at 
    com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate
    (PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:270)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:284)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:445)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:723)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
           
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:280)
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
            (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
            at 
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
            (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
            at          
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
           (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
           [ERROR] http://g2vmcfgsvc04.olqa.preol.dell.com:8080/ConfigService/V3/ConfigDataService.svc?xsd=xsd2 
           [0:0]: (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
           com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: 
           http://g2vmcfgsvc04.olqa.preol.dell.com:8080/ConfigService/V3/ConfigDataService.svc?xsd=xsd2; 
           lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
            at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
            at   
            com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate
           (ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:193)
            at  
         
         com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
            at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:270)
        
    
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
            at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
            at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:284)
            at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:95)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:445)
            at 
  org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:723)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:267)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
            at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:280)
            at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
            at 
          
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
             (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
            at 
            org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
           (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
            at  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuil der.java:56)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
           [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
          [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [INFO] Total time:  38.988 s
          [INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-31T21:34:14+05:30
          [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
          [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.5:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on 
          project SpringBoot_SOAP_Client_Movies: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen- 
           plugin:3.2.5:wsdl2java failed: 
          
    
        http://g2vmcfgsvc04.olqa.preol.dell.com:8080/ConfigService/V3/ConfigDataService.svc?xsd=xsd2 [0,0]: Two 
          declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
          [ERROR] http://g2vmcfgsvc04.olqa.preol.dell.com:8080/ConfigService/V3/ConfigDataService.svc?xsd=xsd2 
          [0,0]: (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
           [ERROR] 
          [ERROR] -> [Help 1]````
`````

Comment: In your WSDL look for declarations of `systemId`.

Comment: I did not find a systemId in my WSDL.